# Joining multiple tables in MYSQL with error (

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
phoneRecord - ID,phone
companies - ID,phone1,phone2, name
contacts - ID, phone1, phone2, companies.ID
```

I want to join tables phone records to companies and contacts, of which i am able to do so, with the following:

```
SELECT 
    phoneRecord.*, 
    companies.ID, 
    contacts.ID, 
FROM phoneRecord
    LEFT JOIN contacts
    ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
    LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2
```

However, I need just one more thing. When a contact is returned, i like to know the company the contact is in(if the contact.companies matches company.id). Is it possible to do this?

I have tried something like:

```
 SELECT 
    phoneRecord.*, 
    companies.ID, 
    companies.name, 
    contacts.ID, 
FROM phoneRecord
    LEFT JOIN contacts
        LEFT JOIN companies ON contacts.company=companies.ID
    ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
    LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2
```

but its giving me an error code 1066: Not unique table/alias:'companies'.

I have switched the code like thomas has suggested, but its giving me the same error. Perhaps I have misinterpreted what he meant. The code is like so:

```
SELECT
    phoneRecord.*, 
    companies.ID, 
    companies.name, 
    contacts.ID, 
FROM phoneRecord
    LEFT JOIN contacts ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
    LEFT JOIN companies ON contacts.company=companies.ID
    LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2
```

I got it to work finally with this:

```
SELECT 
    phoneRecordID,
    phoneRecordPhone,
    companyID,
    contactsID,
    contactsCompany,
    companies.name
    FROM(
SELECT 
    phoneRecord.ID as phoneRecordID, 
    phoneRecord.Phone as phoneRecordPhone,
    companies.ID as companyID, 
    contacts.ID as contactsID, 
    contacts.company as contactsCompany
FROM phoneRecord
    LEFT JOIN contacts
    ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR    phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
    LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2) as result
LEFT JOIN companies ON contactsCompany = companies.id
```

Thanks, this has been super helpful.

Comment: you missed the ON keyword and defining the keys after "LEFT JOIN contacts"

Comment: not that bad your query, just put the " LEFT JOIN companies ON contacts.company=companies.ID" line under the "ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2" line, it's just a syntactical error, you were doing good :)

Comment: It still giving me the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: we are heading to somewhere, dont worry :). The error is just you're using the same alias twice on the same level. Name the "companies" to companies2 at the second LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I retrieve list in result then using left join with contact, Hope this will works for you

```
   SELECT cmid from( SELECT 
   phoneRecord.*, 
   companies.ID as cmid, 
  contacts.ID, 
  FROM phoneRecord
  LEFT JOIN contacts
  ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
   LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2) as result 
    left join contacts on contacts.ID = result.cmid
```

Comment: I have tried using the code you have given, but it doesn't seem to work. The error is: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in  your SQL syntax.....near 'FROM phoneRecord LEFT JOIN contacts ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 O' at line 5

Comment: @yukei wong You got the basic idea from my example , thats the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach to do this -

```
 WITH CompanyInfo As(
   SELECT 
   phoneRecord.ID as phoneRecordID, 
   phoneRecord.Phone as phoneRecordPhone,
   companies.ID as companyID, 
   contacts.ID as contactsID, 
   contacts.company as contactsCompany
   FROM phoneRecord
   LEFT JOIN contacts
   ON phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone1 OR phoneRecord.Phone=contacts.Phone2
   LEFT JOIN companies ON phoneRecord.Phone=companies.phone1 OR phoneRecord.phone=companies.phone2
   )

  SElECT * FROM CompanyInfo 
  LEFT JOIN companies ON CompanyInfo.contactsCompany = companies.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The DBMS is complaining, because you join `companies` twice and it doesn't know which record of the two you are talking about when you use `companies.phone1` for instance. You must give the two different alias names so as to distinguish them. E.g.:

```
left join companies com on p.phone in (com.phone1, com.phone2)
left join contacts con on p.phone in (con.phone1, con.phone2)
left join companies concom on con.company = concom.id
```

However, to me it seems you are selecting two different things:

1. phone records for contacts (in companies)
2. phone records for companies

So you *may* want two queries the results of which you combine:

```
select p.*, com.id as company_id, com.name, con.id as contact_id
from phonerecord p
join contacts con on p.phone in (con.phone1, con.phone2)
join companies com on con.company = com.id
union all
select p.*, com.id as company_id, com.name, null  as contact_id
from phonerecord p
join companies com on p.phone in (com.phone1, com.phone2);
```